# How can I use NSMutable Array as DataSource

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, datasource, uialertview

Sorry I'm new to iOS. I intend to make an `UITableView` inside `UIAlertView`. Finally i have gotten [this tutorial](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2009/07/15/look-uialertview-is-dating-uitableview.html)

I have implemented `UIAlertTableView` class this way

```
UIAlertTableView *alert = [[UIAlertTableView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose a number"
                                                          message:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
alert.tableDelegate = self;
alert.dataSource = self;
alert.tableHeight = 120;
[alert show];
```

However after testing, i got the UIAlert displayed a blank list, with no items appear inside. Previously i have an NSMUtableArray that i want to use as data source. From the tutorial above, seems that assigning data source is done using `alert.dataSource = self`. Yet i'm still wondering how to use my NSMutableArray as the data source and how it relates to `alert.dataSource`?

Comment: You might have to implement data source and delegate methods for tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you need to create a new file as your alertView's table datasource and delegate.
Implement the:

```
@interface MyTableSource: UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyTableSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return 7;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViews cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViews dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"M";
    return cell;

}

@end
```

Create the alert like:

```
UIAlertTableView *alert = [[UIAlertTableView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose a number"
                                                          message:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
MyTableSource *data = [[MyTableSource alloc] init];
alert.tableDelegate = data;
alert.dataSource = data;
alert.tableHeight = 120;
[alert show];
```

**Note:**
I implemented that alertView for testing, there are alot of issues.
You need to call:

`[self layoutAnimated:YES];` instead of `[self setNeedsLayout];` in the alertView class.

Answer (score 0):

You have told UIAlertView your class will be acting as its data source but you would also need to override at least the following UITableView data source methods, Here mutableArray refers to the mutable Array you want to use as data source:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [mutableArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Set up the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = cellValue;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I've made a little edits on my post so i hope it would be more clearly to figure out.

Comment: My UIAlertTableView is created to appear by clicking an item of UITableView inside a UITableViewController.m class. I have implemented those methods you say on that UITableViewController. But it is used to provide datasource for my UITableView, not UIAlertTableView. So, where should I put the code above, in my UITableViewController.m class or in UIAlertTableView.m?